# Visual Studio Extension not working if compile with different VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have installed two version of Visual Studio: 2013 and 2015.
I want to create VS extension (vsix) which will be work with both versions VS, but Package.Initialize method not fired if I debug different version:

Start debug from VS2013 on VS2015 - extension not working, method not called.

Start debug from VS2015 on VS2013 - extension not working, method not called.

Start debug from VS2015 on VS2015 - extension working.

Start debug from VS2013 on VS2013 - extension working.

Package definition contants these attributes:
    [PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
    [InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "1.0", IconResourceID = 400)]
    [Guid(GuidList.guidVSPackageTest20132PkgString)]
    [ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.SolutionExists)]

In manifest Install targets sets to [12.0, 14.0]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To debug a package in a specific VS version you need to adjust two things:

1) In the Debug property page of the project, select the desired devenv.exe executable.

2) In the .csproj file, select the matching VS SDK version for the devenv.exe of step #1 (14.0 for VS 2015, 12.0 for VS 2013):

```
<PropertyGroup>
   ...
   <VisualStudioVersion>14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
   <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
   ...
```